# Adobe AEM Query Buillder API for Javascript and Sightly

Tags: adobe, aem

I am writing code for QueryBuilder API for Adobe Aem in Javascript and Sightly.QueryBuilder API code is available for Java on net but I am not able to find Javascript code for QueryBuilder API.Can anyone guide me how to write for querybuilder API in Javascript and sightly.

Comment: IMO, that's the main problem with the JavaScript WCM Use API. There isn't a JavaScript API per se. You just use Java APIs from a piece of JavaScript that runs on the JVM, effectively obscuring the type system. At the same time, you need to be aware of the return types and possible exceptions. I'm fluent in both Java and JavaScript and I find using the JS WCM Use API a tormenting experience. To write something, you need to read the Javadoc and somehow map it to your JS code. More often than not, it just looks like Java code that has all type declarations replaced with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QueryBuilder Json API.
This is a simple web API reachable via `/bin/querybuilder.json` that can be used in AJAX for example.
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/search/querybuilder-api.html